# using File class to create new text file

Tags: java, file

Is there a way to use the File class to create a new text file?  After doing some research, I tried:

```
import java.io.*;

public class createNewFile
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        File file = new File("newfile.txt");
        boolean b1 = file.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

...but there is still no *newfile.txt* in my source directory.  It would also seem like there would be a void method to do this, instead of having to result to a boolean.  Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with the FIle class, or so I have to result to another class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-to-create-a-file-and-write-to-a-file-in-java          hope it helps

Comment: Rustam: It's false.  Kumar Saurabh: Thanks for the link.  I actually ran across that in my searches, but was wondering if I could do it with the File class since that's what I was taught on as far as reading from files goes.

Comment: That means either file already exist or not created. try printing `file.getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out wero hit the nail on the head.  The file was created in the current working directory, not exactly in the folder where I was looking.  I guess I'm good now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a file but apparently not in your source directory but in the current working directory. You can find the location of this new file with:

```
 System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

One possibility to control the location of the new file is to use an absolute path:

```
 File file = new File("<path to the source dir>/newfile.txt");
 file.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
File f = new File("C:/Path/SubPath/newfile.txt");
f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
f.createNewFile();
```

Also make sure that the path where you are checking and creating the file exists.